# Closed form for the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n[\gcd(i,\lfloor\frac ni\rfloor)=1]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

If we define $f(n)$ as the number of coprime pairs $(i,\lfloor\frac ni\rfloor)$ for $i$ an integer from $1$ to $n$, then $f(n)\sim cn$ for a constant $c\approx 0.7883$.

Because $f(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n[\gcd(i,\lfloor\frac ni\rfloor)=1]$, applying Möbius inversion on the part $1\le \lfloor\frac ni\rfloor \le j$ for an integer $1\le j\le n$ we get

$$\begin{align}f(n)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\gcd\left(i,\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor\right)=1\right]\\&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n{j+1}\right\rfloor}\left[\gcd\left(i,\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor\right)=1\right]\right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^j\sum_{i=\left\lfloor\frac n{k+1}\right\rfloor+1}^{\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor}\left[\gcd(i,k)=1\right]\right)\\&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac n{j+1}\right\rfloor}\left[\gcd\left(i,\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor\right)=1\right]\right)+\left(\sum_{d=1}^j\mu(d)\sum_{x=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac jd\right\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{xd\times d}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{(xd+1)\times d}\right\rfloor\right)\right)\end{align}$$

We can use this to efficiently find $f(n)$ for large $n$, providing evidence for this convergence:

```
(Mathematica)
fp1[n_,b_] := Sum[If[GCD[i,Floor[n/i]]===1,1,0],{i,Floor[n/(b+1)]}] 
fp2[n_,b_] := Sum[MoebiusMu[d]*Sum[Floor[n/(x*d*d)]-Floor[n/(x*d*d+d)],{x,Floor[b/d]}],{d,b}] 
f[n_] := fp1[n,Floor[Sqrt[n]]]+fp2[n,Floor[Sqrt[n]]] 
{f[10^6], f[10^7], f[10^8], f[10^9]} 
> {788314, 7883809, 78838392, 788385339}
```

Taking $j=n$ we can obtain an analytic expression for this constant $c$:

$$\begin{align}c&=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x^2(x+1)}\\&=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(-1)^s\left(\sum_{x=2}\varphi(x)x^{-s-1}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(-1)^s\left(-1+\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+1)}\right)\end{align}$$

It's not obvious how we could reduce further. Is there a closed form for this constant $c$, or possibly any previous results concerning this constant?

Comment: 0.7883854354167303811486041088581026090214330375963322019260340430319228359282864633827353625505526622

Comment: nothing in OEIS